# track created and modified fields automatically in asp.net mvc and mongodb

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

How can I track created and modified date automatically in C# with MongoDB.
I have  database:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string UserCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
    public string UserModified { get; set; }
}

   public  class Income : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Income")]
    public string Income_ { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
}
```

I want to track DateCreated and DateModified automatically.

Comment: [this library](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities) i wrote maintains modified date automatically. creation date/time is embedded in the objectid and can be read like so: `ObjectId.Parse("xxxxxxxxxxxx").CreationTime`